# Multilingual site - login landing pages

Tags: multi-language

We've got a site which is in 10 or so languages, each of them being contained in a template group, en, es, de etc - so essentially the index page of each of these template groups is the homepage of that language and usually, clients from that region don't go to any other language.

However, when they first login they go to the default template group - English - which is the site main template group. From there they choose the language they require.

Is there any way to skip this and have the user redirected to their own language page on login?

Anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Using template groups for different language identifiers is always going to be limiting and not easily scaleable, but to resolve your issue I'd suggest a redirect plugin that takes the user to a specific template that then decides where to take them: [Login Redirect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/login-redirect)

But not sure what you're going to use as an identifier to know where to take them...?  The previous plugin may have the option to return to original page, or you could use [Page History](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/page-history) to see which language page they came from before logging in and taking them there.

Alternatively use [Freemember](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember) to handle your login which could be on your language page itself and I'm fairly certain can redirect back to the page they came from (if that's suitable).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use 'pupe PHP' approach, as described [in this EE SE thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/how-can-i-redirect-a-homepage-depending-on-the-browser-language-settings).

Or you can use [Browser Sniff](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/browser-sniff) add-on.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Peter's answer above,

I would add a hidden field named language and use [EVOPost](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/evopost) to send the value to another template which redirects the user based on the value of the hidden language field.